# My password which are documented is saying invalid

Tags: gmail, account-recovery

My Gmail account keeps not taking my email password that I had written down they are having to be reset about everyday down email the next day it says invalid password. What is going on? It's happening to most of my accounts. I don't have time for this and besides this is so so a mess.

Please let me know what to do?

Answer (score 1):

Sign into your google account and go to:
https://myaccount.google.com/security

This will give you a record of every time there was a password change on your account, every time the password was reset on your account, and every recovery option you have.

This will let you know if you are forgetting your password or it is being changed.